# Storing filters for dplyr `filter()` in a variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to filter multiple dataframes on the same set of conditions. So I'd like to set those filters as a variable outside the `filter()` call.

For example

```
mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl > 4, disp > 100)
```

I tried doing:

```
filters <- c(cyl > 4, disp > 100)
mtcars %>%
  filter(filters)
```

But this doesn't work, because when I set the `filters` variable, it looks for the dataframe column.

```
> filters <- c(cyl > 4, disp > 100)
Error: object 'cyl' not found
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The **rlang** package allows you to create unevaluated expressions that can then be swapped in using special `!!` notation. If you're using **dplyr**, you already have the key parts of **rlang** loaded. Note that for `filter`, it is good practice to be explicit about combining multiple conditions, rather than relying on `filter`'s implicit "anding" of multiple arguments.

```
my.filter <- quo(cyl > 4 & disp > 100)

filter(mtcars, !!my.filter)

    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
4  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
5  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
6  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
7  19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
8  17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
9  16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
```

As Artem pointed out, you can, however, use the comma notation with the plural `quos` function and the `!!!` operator:

```
my.filter <- quos(cyl > 4, disp > 100)

filter(mtcars, !!!my.filter)
```

Comment: You don't have to stick to `&`. Multiple conditions can be stored using `my.filter <- quos( cyl > 4, disp > 100 )`. You just need `!!!` when unquoting a list: `filter(mtcars, !!!my.filter)`

Comment: Nice, didn't know that!